# .net core 6 blazor wasm hosted change route in client index.hml <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

Tags: iis, publish, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0, hosted

do you know how I can change the
_framework directory,

for security? Why does this directory show security information?

I have one solution
client
server
shared

I have 127.0.0.1/site/_framework/blazor.boot.json
and show information private

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSXTW.png)

Help me, please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In short, show the sensitive information about assembly and others is expected behavior.

From the design of Blazor WASM, this is unavoidable. This is the same as static files such as Javascript, confidential information should not be kept, but we can obfuscate it in a certain way. But I don't think it is necessary.

Regarding Blazor WASM usage recommendations and safety, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224293/blazor-dlls-can-users-access-them-and-decompile) will inspire you.